# Shorthand for if true then function?

Tags: javascript, shorthand

Let me get to this point straight. So I found a shorthand on an Instagram post for something like this:

```js
const bool = true
function myFunction (){
//smth
}
if(bool){
myFunction
}
```

I can't remember what it was, something with the && operator. Anyone?

sorry for being a bit off topic but I really need this.

Comment: Your code doesn't do anything, did you intend to call `myFunction`?

Comment: `bool && myFunction()`… But why? Do you have a shortage of lines or something?

Comment: `bool` is `const` and `true`, there is no need to check it.

Comment: yep i needed to call the function  my bad I missed the brackets, and yeah I do lack characters. thx anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you're thinking of just using `&&` as it short circuits

```js
const bool = true;
const notBool = false;
function myFunction(){ console.log("hello, world!") };

bool && myFunction();
notBool && myFunction(); // nada!
```